Web con springboot en Java
estoy tratando de hacer un login con Springboot en java, donde paso una contraseña y un usuario y, de ser válidos, lo redirige a otro HTML. Estoy utilizando Postgres como base de datos y solo tengo tres tablas: Persona, Tipodocumento y Productos. Tipodocumentos tiene una relación uno a mucho con la tabla persona. Tengo dos preguntas, la primera es que si la lógica dentro de la función login es correcta, la cual está en la clase PersonaController.  De no ser el caso, ¿qué debería modificar? La segunda pregunta, ¿cómo debería ir estructurado el HTML para que sea capaz de enviar los datos a la función?
Clase Persona:

    @Entity
        @Table(name = "Producto", schema = "dh")
        public class Producto {
    
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private long id;
    
            private String nombre;
            private String descripcion;
            private String precio;
            private String cantidad;
            private String FechaLlegada;
            private String FechaExpiracion;
    
            public long getId() {
                return id;
            }
    
            public void setId(long id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
    
            public String getNombre() {
                return nombre;
            }
    
            public void setNombre(String nombre) {
                this.nombre = nombre;
            }
    
            public String getDescripcion() {
                return descripcion;
            }
    
            public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
                this.descripcion = descripcion;
            }
    
            public String getPrecio() {
                return precio;
            }
    
            public void setPrecio(String precio) {
                this.precio = precio;
            }
    
            public String getCantidad() {
                return cantidad;
            }
    
            public void setCantidad(String cantidad) {
                this.cantidad = cantidad;
            }
    
            public String getFechaLlegada() {
                return FechaLlegada;
            }
    
            public void setFechaLlegada(String fechaLlegada) {
                FechaLlegada = fechaLlegada;
            }
    
            public String getFechaExpiracion() {
                return FechaExpiracion;
            }
    
            public void setFechaExpiracion(String fechaExpiracion) {
                FechaExpiracion = fechaExpiracion;
            }
    
            public Producto(long id, String nombre, String descripcion, String precio, String cantidad, String fechaLlegada, String fechaExpiracion) {
                super();
                this.id = id;
                this.nombre = nombre;
                this.descripcion = descripcion;
                this.precio = precio;
                this.cantidad = cantidad;
                FechaLlegada = fechaLlegada;
                FechaExpiracion = fechaExpiracion;
            }
    
            public Producto() {super();}
    
            public Producto(String nombre, String descripcion, String precio, String cantidad, String fechaLlegada, String fechaExpiracion) {
                super();
                this.nombre = nombre;
                this.descripcion = descripcion;
                this.precio = precio;
                this.cantidad = cantidad;
                FechaLlegada = fechaLlegada;
                FechaExpiracion = fechaExpiracion;
            }
        } 


Clase Repository:

    @Repository
    public interface PersonaRepositoryInter extends JpaRepository<Persona, Long> {
        Persona findByUsuarioAndContrasena(String usuario, String contrasena);
    }


Clase Service:

    @Service
    public class PersonaService{
        @Autowired
        private PersonaRepositoryInter personaRepositoryInter;
    
        public Persona savePersona(Persona persona){
    
            return personaRepositoryInter.save(persona);
    
        }
    
        public Optional<Persona> findById(Long id){
            return personaRepositoryInter.findById(id);
        }
    
        public Page<Persona> getAllPersona(Integer page, Integer size, Boolean eneablePagination){
            return personaRepositoryInter.findAll(eneablePagination ? PageRequest.of(page, size): Pageable.unpaged());
        }
    
        public void deletePersona(Long id){
            personaRepositoryInter.deleteById(id);
        }
    
        public Persona editPersona(Persona persona){
            if(persona.getId() != 0 && personaRepositoryInter.existsById(persona.getId()))
            {
                return personaRepositoryInter.save(persona);
            }
            return null;
        }
    
    
        public boolean existById(Long id) {
            return personaRepositoryInter.existsById(id);
        }
    
        public List<Persona> findAll() {
            return personaRepositoryInter.findAll();
        }
    }


Clase Controller:

    @Controller
    public class PersonaController {
        @Autowired
        private PersonaRepositoryInter personaRepositoryInter;
    
        @Autowired
        private TipodocumentoRepository tipodocumentoRepository;
    
        @GetMapping("/personas")
        public String ListaPersonas(Model model){
            List<Persona> listaPersona = personaRepositoryInter.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("listaPersona", listaPersona);
            return "personas";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/nuevo")
        public String mostrarFormularioDeNuevaPersona(Model model){
            List<Tipodocumento> listaTipodocumento = tipodocumentoRepository.findAll();
    
            model.addAttribute("persona", new Persona());
            model.addAttribute("listaTipodocumento", listaTipodocumento);
            return "persona_formulario";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/guardar")
        public String guardarPersona(Persona persona){
            personaRepositoryInter.save(persona);
            return "redirect:/personas";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/inicio")
        public String regreso() {
            return "index";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/personas/eliminar/{id}")
        public String deletePersona(@PathVariable ("id") Long id, Model model){
            personaRepositoryInter.deleteById(id);
            return "redirect:/personas";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/personas/editar/{id}")
        public String EditarPersona(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model modelo){
            Persona persona = personaRepositoryInter.findById(id).get();
            modelo.addAttribute("persona", persona);
    
            List<Tipodocumento> listaTipodocumento = tipodocumentoRepository.findAll();
            modelo.addAttribute("listaTipodocumento", listaTipodocumento);
    
            return "persona_formulario";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/login")
        public String login(@RequestParam String usuario, @RequestParam String contrasena, Model model) {
            // Consulta la base de datos para buscar coincidencias
            Persona persona = personaRepositoryInter.findByUsuarioAndContrasena(usuario, contrasena);
    
            if (persona != null) {
                // Si el usuario existe y la contraseña coincide, redirige a productos.html
                return "redirect:/productos.html";
            } else {
                // Agrega un mensaje de error al modelo y vuelve al formulario de inicio de sesión
                model.addAttribute("error", "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
                return "index";
            }
    
    
        }
    }


Si necesitan alguna otra parte del código avísenme, gracias

La lógica de tu función login está bien para un caso básico, pero podemos mejorarla un poco. Primero, no deberías almacenar ni comparar contraseñas en texto plano, ya que es un riesgo de seguridad. Lo ideal es que uses BCrypt o un sistema similar para cifrar las contraseñas antes de guardarlas en la base de datos y compararlas de manera segura.
    Persona persona = personaRepositoryInter.findByUsuario(usuario);
if (persona != null && BCrypt.checkpw(contrasena, persona.getContrasena())) {
    return "redirect:/productos.html";
}

También sería bueno validar que los campos no lleguen vacíos, para evitar errores inesperados, tenlo en cuenta.
En cuanto al HTML para enviar los datos al login, puedes hacer algo sencillo como esto:
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" required>
    
    <label for="contrasena">Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" required>
    
    <button type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
</form>
<p th:if="${error}" th:text="${error}"></p>

Esto le dice a tu backend que capture los datos de usuario y contraseña al hacer clic en el botón. Además, el mensaje de error se mostrará si algo falla en el login.

Después de batallar un poco con el código que me pasaste pude resolver el problema. Muchas gracias por responder.
